# Python tensorflow error, sys has no attribute getdlflags

Tags: python, tensorflow

I Just attempted to install tensorflow for python and when I went to the console to see if the **init**.py was working it returned this error. I installed it manualy without pip or any other package manager.

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\*username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    _default_dlopen_flags = sys.getdlopenflags()
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'getdlopenflags'
```

Comment: By looking at path of `__init__.py`, it seems that you are running `tensorflow` on a Windows machine. `getdlopenflags` is supported only on Unix platform. see [sys.getdlopenflags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getdlopenflags) documentation

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow is not supported on Windows yet. Please follow [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17) github issue which tracks TensorFlow Windows support.