# keras import error no attribute 'getdlopenflags'

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, keras

I am new to `keras`, and I have downloaded `theano`, `scipy` and `numpy` modules, but when I want to `import keras`, the command window tells me that

```
"Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\eclipse\dasd\aaa\aaaa.py", line 7, in <module>
import keras
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from . import backend
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
from .tensorflow_backend import *
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
_default_dlopen_flags = sys.getdlopenflags()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getdlopenflags'"
```

my computer system is win7-64 and I haven't downloaded CUDA because my graphics card is ATI's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python tensorflow error, sys has no attribute getdlflags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026865/python-tensorflow-error-sys-has-no-attribute-getdlflags)

Comment: @liori well, yes but the solution is different in this case as theano can be used.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yeah, I noticed that only after the vote. I don't think I can take it back?

Comment: @liori you can, just cancel the cv and delete the link :D

Answer (score 0):

Keras is using Tensorflow by default. You need to explicitly switch to Theano, see the [official documentation](https://keras.io/backend/) for the current procedure, for example by setting the environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND` to `theano`.

Comment: thanks  I changed the environment variables and  keras works fine!